# JQuery validate with potential user interaction

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-validate

I have a form which contains an address to be validated, which requires calling a web service, and if it's not valid, the user is given a modal JQuery UI dialog to override. How can I make this work, since the popup is asynchronous, the validate call is complete before the user is able to choose whether to avoid the validation rule?

Edit: I think I've made a design decision, which is probably better in terms of separation of concerns. The more I think about it, bringing up a dialog to allow essentially editing of the data within the validation phase doesn't make much sense. So validation will be sync and the override will be done within the context of the data entry process instead. (FYI, there is more than just override, there is also potentially pick list to choose from possible matching addresses, so choosing one would essentially change the underlying data you're validating in the first place).

Answer (score -1):

you can pass a callback function to $.getJSON or $.ajax like this:

```
$.getJSON('ajax/test.json', {address: $('#myInput').val()}, function(data) {
  var items = [];

  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
  });

  $('<ul/>', {
    'class': 'my-new-list',
    html: items.join('')
  }).appendTo('body');
});
```

this is from the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

here a little more tailored to your needs

```
$.getJSON('validateAddress.json', {address: $('#myInput').val()}, function(data)
{
   if( data.result == 'ok') 
   {
      $('#override').dialog();
   } else {
      alert('invalid address');
   }
});
```

Comment: $.getJSON is asynchronous, he needs synchnorous

Comment: if he moves the logic into the callback, this should still work, maybe i am not understanding the question correctly

Comment: It's a jquery dialog, not an alert, and therefore not blocking.